# UIKit issue using xcode 11.4.1 in iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, ios12

[image]Hello I am developing using xcode 11.4.1 now in ios 12.4 devices I am not able to change UI like Labels text color, button title button image programetically. I dont know what is the issue. Event the constaints are not changing programtically

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. Add relevant code. Explain what happens and what should be happening. See [ask]

Comment: Actully I am not able to update any UIKit property, NS Constraint from code @Paulw11

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise how can we help?

Comment: @Paulw11 self.videoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "video"), for: .normal) this is not working in ios 12 where it is working ios 13

Comment: Define "not working". What does this code have to do with the images in your question.  Ideally edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: @Paulw11 If I write label.textColor = .red it will change color in ios 13 but not in ios 12, I f i right constraint.constant = 50 it will work in ios 13 but not in 12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214561/discussion-between-anshul-king-and-paulw11).

Comment: Please edit the question and post the full code where you are seeing the issue, e.g. the function these UI changes are happening, and/or the views you're trying to update. There is not enough information here for us to help you.